# Angular Material 2 vertical stepper with validations and go to next

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using angular material current latest [version](https://material.angular.io/). I want to use their vertical stepper component for mobile layout. I need to use the linear attribute so that the user may not be able to proceed until the previous steps are not completed. I am also putting some validations and error messages so that the users get to know what they are missing.

Upto this above steps everything is working. validations are working, error messages are showing, user is not allowed to go to the next steps. the only problem is that even after completing all the required fields the user is still not able to go the next step and the current step is not closing as shown in the demo.

Here is an example of what I actually want to achive. [[Example for the demo](https://kinark.github.io/Materialize-stepper/?email=ssdfdsf%40sdfsdfdf&password=sdfsdfdsfds)]. Not necessarily the label highlighting itself is required. just want to go to the next step and collapse the current step once completed.

**Here is my HTML Code:**

```
<mat-vertical-stepper linear>
<!--First Step starts-->
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
  <div class="step-container" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="90" fxFlexOffset="5" fxFlex.gt-md="40" fxFlexOffset.gt-md="25">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Shipping</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="First name" [formControl]="firstName" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required')">
          Please enter your first name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name" [formControl]="lastName" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="lastName.hasError('required')">
           Please enter your last name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button class="btn-submit" color="primary" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</mat-step>
<!--First Step ends-->
<!--Second Step starts-->
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" optional>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
        Done
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
  </mat-step>
  <!--Second Step starts-->
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

**My Component Typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition } from '../router.animations';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css'],
  animations: [routerTransition()],
  host: {'[@routerTransition]': ''}
})
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {

  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  firstName = new FormControl ();
  lastName = new FormControl();


  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

I presume its because when I am using `FormControl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding your inputs to form controls that are not part of your `FormGroup`.

Change

```
firstName = new FormControl ();
lastName = new FormControl();
```

To

```
get firstName() { return this.firstFormGroup.get('firstName'); }
get lastName() { return this.firstFormGroup.get('lastName'); }
```

This is because `FormBuilder` creates the `FormControls` for you.

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  // creates the internal firstName FormControl
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  // creates the internal lastName FormControl
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution Tomasz Kula provided, the better way to resolve this would to use the [`formControlName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#register-formcontrol-within-a-group) attribute on your inputs since you're already setting the `[formGroup]` input on your form element.

By using getters, you may be [causing unnecessary function calls](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) during page render & change cycle events.

Here's an example:

```html
<mat-vertical-stepper linear>
<!--First Step starts-->
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
  <div class="step-container" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="90" fxFlexOffset="5" fxFlex.gt-md="40" fxFlexOffset.gt-md="25">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Shipping</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="firstName" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required')">
          Please enter your first name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name" formControlName="lastName" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="lastName.hasError('required')">
           Please enter your last name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button class="btn-submit" color="primary" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</mat-step>
<!--First Step ends-->
<!--Second Step starts-->
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" optional>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
        Done
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
  </mat-step>
  <!--Second Step starts-->
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```